# How to Enable the user install the bot by default and not tab on teams app manifest

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, web-app-manifest

Hi guys I have been trying to enable my bot on default, the bot needs to be installed directly to the Microsoft team's channel.
Below is the schema of my app manifest in teams

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.11",
    "version": "1.6",
    "id": "xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx",
    "packageName": "com.xxxxx.microsoftteams.jira",
    "developer": {
        "name": "xxxxxxx",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.xxxxx.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.xxxxx.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.xxxxx.com/license",
        "mpnId": "xxxxx"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "xxxx",
        "full": "xxxx"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "xxxxx",
        "full": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "configurableTabs": [],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "conversations",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        },
        {
            "entityId": "about",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        },
        {
            "entityId": "xx",
            "name": "xx",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "search",
                    "type": "query",
                    "title": "Search",
                    "description": "Search for issues in xxx",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "fetchTask": false,
                    "context": [
                        "commandBox",
                        "compose"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "search",
                            "title": "Search",
                            "description": "Search",
                            "inputType": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "defaultInstallScope": "team",
    "defaultGroupCapability": {
        "meetings": "bot",
        "team": "bot",
        "groupchat": "bot"
    },
    "validDomains": [
        "xxx",
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "xxx-xxxx-xxxx",
        "resource": "http://"
    }
}
```

So if you look carefully you will find out that I have added `defaultInstallScope` to route the installation to teams and `defaultGroupCapability` has teams specifying that it should install the bot to the teams. But it's not working. Please does anybody know anything about this?

Comment: defaultGroupCapability provides the default capability that will be added to the team, groupchat, or meeting. Select a tab, bot, or connector as the default capability for your app, but you must ensure that you have provided the selected capability in your app definition .Could you just check it once? or share the error log?
Ref Doc:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/add-default-install-scope

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: Exactly @Sayali-MSFT I already have the defaultGroupCapability defined in the app manifest, but it doesn't work, the intention here, is that when I install on app manifest, it on default routes to the default install scope ```teams``` of which teams is meant to install the bot which has been defined in defaultGroupCapacity.

But it doesn't install to the teams, it installs in the personal chatbot

Comment: @Tochukwu Ozurumba - We are tried with the defaultGroupCapability defined in the app manifest.It's working Fine for us.Could you please check it once? getting same as mention in screenshot or anything else then share the error log or screenshots? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXcP6.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctGXK.png 3.https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTzHK.png

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, So I checked your earlier comment and found out that what you described there was already what I have in place, where if I want to install my bot, I select the team/channel I want to install the bot to and also I choose whether I want to install the tab or a bot to that channel or chat destination.

My main question, speaking from a customer perspective, is there not a way to bypass all that process by clicking install bot and it takes you to a destination as described by the defaultInstallScope and defaultGroupCapability, it installs as we have it specified in the app manifest

Comment: @Tochukwu Ozurumba-It doesn't seem to be possible
There is no other option for us.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thanks, I already assumed it might not be possible now, are there any plans to work on it or to make it available?

Comment: @Tochukwu Ozurumba-Currently there is no plan for this.
Could you please raise a user voice here:-
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

Answer (score 0):

defaultGroupCapability provides the default capability that will be added to the team, groupchat, or meeting. Select a tab, bot, or connector as the default capability for your app, but you must ensure that you have provided the selected capability in your app definition .Could you just check it once? or share the error log?

Ref Doc:-[Configure default install options for your Microsoft Teams app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/add-default-install-scope)